# How to slow down CD-ROM (optical drive) under Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, compact-disc, noise

My laptop's optical drive (Optiarc DVD RW AD-7560A) is quite loud when reading a disk.
 For my purpose I don't need reading at full speed, and 8-16x would be more than enough (1-4x would do as well). Could you please suggest free software which would allow me to slow down the drive when needed?

What I tried:

- MagicSpeed from Samsung - doesn't work, needs Samsung drive
- Nero DriveSpeed from Nero 9 -- works, but only 30-day trial
- OptiDriveControl - works, but only 30-day trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has quite a number of tools you can use:

[http://forum.rpc1.org/viewtopic.php?t=26740](https://web.archive.org/web/20150513103702/http://forum.rpc1.org/viewtopic.php?t=26740)

Comment: Can you please add some explanation and links here? That would be much more useful.